# Validate and submit a form containing data and a file using ajax/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form containing data and a file input fields, 
I want to submit and validate this form using jquery and ajax through one script.

Below is my form:

```
<form id="datas" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" value="" />
    <input name="pic" type="file" />
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now I have this code to validate the data

```
$('#datas').validate({
    rules: {
        firstName:{
            required: true,
            minlength: 2,
            maxlength: 100
        }   

    },
    messages: {
        firstName: {
            required: "Please Enter first name",
            minlength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters"),
            maxlength: jQuery.format("Enter atmost {0} characters"),
        }
    }
});
```

Then I have a seperate code that could submit the form

```
$("#datas").submit(function(){

    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: sucess.php,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

**QUESTION:**

Please how can I combine these two scripts to validate the file and data fields and also submit to the success page.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can set required attribute for the file field as well as such:

```
   rules: {
        ...
        pic:{
            required: true
        },
```